# add tax zone in oscommerce

Tags: php, oscommerce

I am using oscommerce for my site. If product is **purchased from certain state** then tax will be applicable otherwise no tax for the product.

How can i do this in oscommerce?

Comment: Still using that creepy thing called osCommerce?! :S

Comment: I suspect that "state" means one of the 28 Indian states, given the location of avinash, but it's unclear from the question.

Comment: The residency of the developer doesn't necessarily imply the residency of the users.

Comment: Avinash - Magento is the new darling of e-commerce.

Comment: With a similarly horrifying code base, I'm told.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following instructions will set it up so that when a customer purchases a certain product, a specific tax rate will be applied according to the state listed in their delivery address.

#### Locations/Taxes > Zones

Look over the existing zones (states/provinces) in the admin. If yours is in here, skip this step.

Otherwise:

- Click **new zone**.
- Set the Zone Name to the State name
- Set Zones Code as State code abbreviation. (e.g. NY for New York)

#### Locations/Taxes > Tax Zones

- Click **insert**
- Enter a Zone Name
- Click **insert**

On your newly created tax zone, click on the folder icon.

- Click **insert**
- Select the relevant country from the first drop down list
- Select the zone as created in the previous section (Locations/Taxes > Zones)
- Click **insert**

#### Locations/Taxes > Tax Classes

- Click **new tax class**
- Enter a Tax Class Title
- Click **insert**

#### Locations/Taxes > Tax Rates

- Click **new tax rate**
- Select a Tax Class Title created earlier
- Select the relevant Zone, also created earlier
- Enter the tax rate you want to apply for this particular tax zoning
- Enter "1" for Priority
- Click **insert**

#### Catalog

Select and edit the product(s) that will be affected by the new tax zone.

In the Tax Class section, select your newly created tax zone and enter the markup and costings as appropriate.

Now, when a registered customer views and adds to cart the product, and their delivery state matches the tax zone specifications you've set up, they will see this tax rate applied to the product.

For all other customers, they will not see the additional tax rate.

You cannot, without modification, set up more than one tax zone on a product.